# Use window.matchMedia to pass variable into slider options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code (some of which might not make a ton of sense...), but here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

1) Use the window.matchMedia key to determine the width of the screen 
2) create a function based on the media query that prints out a value to the variable gridSize
3) Pass that getGridSize function into a list of options for a slider.

The code I have is

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );

var gridSize = getGridSize();

 function getGridSize() { 
 if (mq.matches) {
  // window width is at least 500px
    gridSize = 4;
} else {
  // window width is less than 500px
  gridSize = 1;
   }
  };

    flexslider.vars.minItems = gridSize;
    flexslider.vars.maxItems = gridSize;


$('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      animationSpeed: 400,
      animationLoop: false,
      itemWidth: 210,
      itemMargin: 5,
      minItems: getGridSize(),
      maxItems: getGridSize(),
      prevText: "",
      nextText: ""

  });
```

I amalgamated 2 pieces of code, trying to sort out the bits that I need from each, so it feels a bit frankenstein-like, and is probably why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you set 'flexslider.vars' you need to declare it somewhere.
2. You are missing a 'resize' listener on the window

```

```
var flexslider = {vars: {}};
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );

function getGridSize() { 
  return mq.matches ? 4 : 1;
};

$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  animationSpeed: 400,
  animationLoop: false,
  itemWidth: 210,
  itemMargin: 5,
  minItems: getGridSize(),
  maxItems: getGridSize(),
  prevText: "",
  nextText: ""
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var gridSize = getGridSize();
  flexslider.vars.minItems = gridSize;
  flexslider.vars.maxItems = gridSize;
});
```

```